# create new columns with mutate_all

Tags: r, dplyr

I have some data that looks like this:

```
  Year Revenue Cost Rent
1 2016    3000    4  100
2 2017    4000    5  100
3 2018    5000    6  100

df <- data.frame(stringsAsFactors=FALSE,
        Year = c(2016L, 2017L, 2018L),
     Revenue = c(3000L, 4000L, 5000L),
        Cost = c(4L, 5L, 6L),
        Rent = c(100L, 100L, 100L)
)
```

I'd like to divide everything say as a percentage of `Rent`:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- df %>% mutate_at(vars(Revenue:Rent), funs(. /Rent))
```

which works perfectly.

```
  Year Revenue Cost Rent
1 2016      30 0.04    1
2 2017      40 0.05    1
3 2018      50 0.06    1
```

The only thing: I've lost my original columns.

How can I do the `mutate_all`, so that I have new columns, say called `Revenue_percentage_of_rent`, `Cost_percentage_of_rent` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The usage of `funs` would be deprecated in favor of `list` from `dplyr_0.8.0`  So, the option would be

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    mutate_at(vars(Revenue:Rent), list(percentage_of_rent = ~  ./Rent))
#  Year Revenue Cost Rent Revenue_percentage_of_rent Cost_percentage_of_rent Rent_percentage_of_rent
#1 2016    3000    4  100                         30                    0.04                       1
#2 2017    4000    5  100                         40                    0.05                       1
#3 2018    5000    6  100                         50                    0.06                       1
```

Answer (score 2):

Name the column in the function in `mutate_at`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate_at(vars(Revenue:Rent), funs(percentage_of_rent = . /Rent))
```

You can do it with `mutate_all` but then it will also divide the `Year` column by `Rent` which I suppose you don't need.

A workaround to use `mutate_all` would be

```
df %>% select(-Year) %>% mutate_all(funs(percentage_of_rent = . /Rent))
```

but you loose `Year` column here.